# Parsing nested data from CSV

Tags: csv, haskell

Consider the following:

```
data DataTrain = DataTrain
    {
        item :: Text,
        user :: Text,
        dval :: Double
    }
instance FromNamedRecord DataTrain where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        DataTrain
            <$> m .: "item"
            <*> m .: "user"
            <*> m .: "dval"
```

This implements the CSV reading interface in cassava and allows reading `DataTrain` from a CSV file. Now, I would like to parse the following:

```
data DataIn = DataIn
    {
        item :: Text,
        user :: Text
    }
data DataTrain = DataTrain
    {
        dataIn :: DataIn,
        dval :: Double
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect as above using a concise syntax? The following:

```
instance FromNamedRecord DataIn where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        DataIn <$> m .: "item"
               <*> m .: "user"
instance FromNamedRecord DataTrain where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        DataTrain
            <$> m .: "???" -- What to put here?
            <*> m .: "dval"
```

does not seem to work. I'm still a newbie to Haskell so I'm not sure what would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invoke the `DataIn` parser from the `DataTrain` parser like so, because `parseNamedRecord` returns a `Parser`:

```
instance FromNamedRecord DataTrain where
  parseNamedRecord m = DataTrain
    <$> parseNamedRecord m
    <*> m .: "dval"
```

Its type, and thus the correct instance to call, is inferred from the type of the first parameter of `DataTrain`.

You don’t need monadic bind (`>>=`) here because the parser doesn’t have any “data dependencies”—you aren’t deciding *how* to parse the input based on the input.

---

Here’s a little refresher on how you can combine parsers—or any monadic type in fact. When you want to apply a pure function to a pure argument, you use juxtaposition or `$`:

```
SomeUnaryConstructor someValue
SomeUnaryConstructor $ someValue
```

In a similar way, to apply a pure function to the result of a parser, use `fmap`, a.k.a. `<$>`:

```
SomeUnaryConstructor <$> someParser
fmap SomeUnaryConstructor someParser

-- =

do
  result <- someParser
  pure $ SomeUnaryConstructor result
```

To apply multiple arguments, chain them with `<*>`:

```
SomeBinaryConstructor <$> someParser <*> anotherParser

-- =

do
  result1 <- someParser
  result2 <- anotherParser
  pure $ SomeBinaryConstructor result1 result2
```

This is left-associative—`SomeBinaryConstructor <$> someParser` is a parser that returns a partially applied function; then that function `<*> anotherParser` fills the next argument of the function with the result of `anotherParser`.

To apply a parser to the *result of another parser*, use `>>=` or its flipped version `=<<`:

```
someParser =<< anotherParser =<< yetAnotherParser

-- =

do
  result1 <- yetAnotherParser
  result2 <- anotherParser result1
  someParser result2
```

The whole table looks like:

```
 ($)  ::                    (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b
(<$>) :: Functor     f =>   (a ->   b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a ->   b) -> f a -> f b
(=<<) :: Monad       f =>   (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b
```

In other words:

- `function $ value`
- `function <$> parser that returns value`
- `parser that returns function <*> parser that returns value`
- `function that returns parser =<< parser that returns value`

Comment: shouldn't it be `makeSomeParser =<< makeAnotherParser =<< yetAnotherParser`?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, the following seems to be the correct way to chain two parsers. Recall:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
```

we can have that

```
instance FromNamedRecord DataIn where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        DataIn <$> m .: "item"
               <*> m .: "user"
instance FromNamedRecord DataTrain where
    parseNamedRecord m =
        (parseNamedRecord m :: Csv.Parser DataIn)
            >>= (\x -> DataTrain <$> m .: "dval")
```

The part where `<$>` begins the construction of a parser is still a mystery